# Get size of image loading through URL

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, uiimageview

In my application I am displaying feed in tableview. Image is coming through URL. I want to calculate cell height dynamically based on image size. But I get image after cell get load.

How to achieve dynamic height of cell based on image size?

I hope my question is clear and I will get solution here.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you are doing lazy loading in your tableview so image data will come after table reload so you can't get the Image size before sending request, get data and apply data to image

Comment: if I don't use lazy loading than it will not scroll tableview smoothly.

Comment: The best way is set the UIImage view size fixed in UITableviewCell and  resize downloaded image for fixed size

Comment: Ya i know that so i suggest above comment

Comment: Or you can get the size of the image from the API(Server) where you call your image url.

Comment: will it take time at server side to give image's size in api ?

Comment: i think on server side, Original image is already there so by calling such function you can get the size of that image and just get it in the api response

Comment: But the better way is set fixed size UIImageview in cell and resize downloaded image as per cell imageview size

Comment: Hey @SS if you have got the solution for this, please make a time to share it here, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When your images are loaded, you can calculate all heights for your rows, and if your  heightForRowAtIndexPath method is implemented respectively just call [tableView reloadTable].

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to get the image sizes in the api itself if the service is handled by you itself. Since without getting the image downloaded you will not get its size.

Other way would be to keep the `imageview` in table row in a constant size and aspect fill the image inside it as most of the applications do.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

But you can use image downloading dispatch_async.

```
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://static.hugedomains.com/images/logo_huge_domains.gif"]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NSLog(@"image height: %f",image.size.height);
    NSLog(@"image width: %f",image.size.width);
```

Comment: But it will take time to load image. and I can't let users to wait till image get load.

Comment: Using same to load image.